# Yii2 Page does not redirect after using resize class

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

am having a problem with page redirect.It works fine at my local but the problem is with web server 
I had downloaded the resize script from here 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php--net-10362
used it as a model,here is my code

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
  $model = $this->findModel($id);
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
    if ($model->validate()) {
        $name       = $_FILES['Banner']['name']['image'];
        $filename   = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME).'_220x333';
        $ext        = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $newName        =preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\._]+/", "-", strtolower($filename) ).'.'.$ext;      
        $fullImgSource= Yii::getAlias('@backend') . '/web/assets2/banner_original/' .$newName;
        $model->image->saveAs($fullImgSource);

        $re200=Yii::getAlias('@backend') . '/web/assets2/banner' .$newName;

        $resizeObj = new resize($fullImgSource);
        $resizeObj -> resizeImage(220, 333, 'auto');
        $resizeObj -> saveImage($re200, 100);

        $model->image=$newName;
        if ($model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success','Banner Updated Successfully');
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }
  } else{
    return $this->render('update', [
      'model' => $model,
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: i guess your model isn't saved or at least `$model->save()` is returning false. Add a `var_dump($model->getErrors())` in an else statement so you would see whats the cause.